# Load keras model in tensorflow backend without reset parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model where the weight is already loaded, see `model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')`. Now I want to process it, see the python code Process(model),

```
def Process(model):
    from keras import backend as K
    global _TF_SESSION
    if _TF_SESSION is not None:
        _TF_SESSION.close()
    _TF_SESSION = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    sess = _TF_SESSION
    K.set_session(sess)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

The problem is that `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` resets the weights in my model. But I don't want to reset this, is there a way to solve this? I tried several ways for example `sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([]))`, it throws an error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value`
I don't want to save the keras model to model files and reload. Also, I want to initialized the tf session inside the function `Process()` rather than outside. What is the suggested way to achieve this (not reset the weights)? Thank you very much!